# jQuery autocomplete to populate another div and select item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In my rails v4 app, I'm using a jQuery autocomplete on an input field.

I'd like to make some changes to put the autocomplete results in a different div, and not show them right below the input. I've found answers which show how to do this (for ex: https://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/r5ZmE/), but my problem is that I can't get the select event to fire when one of the items in the other div is selected.

I've created a fork of the above jfiddle in which I try to fire the event: https://jsfiddle.net/ronmexico15/3Lyn6b68/

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    alert('Make this fire!');
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.